# Retrieve class values from selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` and I want to get the selected values back in bean. But the value I receive 
when I select an item from the menu it's a string, representing the type field from the `CategorizationBean`.
I just want when I select an item from the table, to get the whole `CategorizationBean` structure in the bean.

This is the snippet from the xhtml page:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Categorization"  
                      value="#alertMB.selectedCategories}" 
                      converter="com.converter.CategoryConverter">

    <f:selectItems value="#{alertMB.categoryDomainEntry}"
                   var="category"
                   itemLabel="#{category.type}"
                   itemValue="#{category}"/> 
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Snippet from bean:

```
public List<CategorizationBean> getSelectedCategories() {
        return selectedCategories;
}

public void setSelectedCategories(List<CategorizationBean> selectedCategories) {
    this.selectedCategories = selectedCategories;
}

public class CategorizationBean implements Serializable{
    private String type;
    private long id;
```

Comment: How does your converter look like (`com.converter.CategoryConverter`)? Does it adequately accept and return a correct type? (In this expression, `value="#alertMB.selectedCategories}"`,  there is an invalid syntax (missing a `{` after the `#` symbol). I avoided considering it a typo).

Comment: It is indeed a typo. The converter looks like this:

    Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent     component, String value) {       
  //code
        }

    Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent     component,
            Object value) {
            return ((CategorizationBean)value).getType();
The problem is that if i change the getAsObject function value parameter from String to CategorizationBean i can't override it anymore.

Comment: @AlexStratulat please include your converter in the question, and what is exactly wrong with your converter ? do you have some errors or you just can't understand why it's not working (for some reason you don't know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have missed by using a list of beans, I use this example and it works:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="slctRdBtn"
                                value="#{yourBean.compLovDtgrid}"
                                converter="compLovDtgridConverter">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{yourBean.listCompLovDtgrid}"
                                    var="rdbtn" itemLabel="#{rdbtn.vjlrLibelleRep}"
                                    itemValue="#{rdbtn}" />
                            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

and for the converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=CompLovDtgrid.class , value="compLovDtgridConverter")
public class CompLovDtgridConverter implements Converter{
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
{
    return (value instanceof CompLovDtgrid) ? ((CompLovDtgrid) value).getVjlrCodeRep() : null;
}
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,String value)
{
    if(value == null)
        return null;

    YourBean data = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{yourBean}", YourBean.class);

    for(CompLovDtgrid compLovDtgrid : data.getListCompLovDtgrid())
    {
        if(compLovDtgrid.getVjlrCodeRep().equals(value))
            return compLovDtgrid;
    }

    throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to CompLovDtgrid", value)));
}
```

}

and for the list, I use:

```
public List<CompLovDtgrid> getListCompLovDtgrid() 
    {
        return listCompLovDtgrid;
    }

    public void setListCompLovDtgrid(List<CompLovDtgrid> listCompLovDtgrid) {
        this.listCompLovDtgrid = listCompLovDtgrid;
    }
```